# I'm looking for a program that can automate opening/closing a program

Tags: software-rec, automation

I am looking a for a program to remember things with these features:

- **Open files or programs in my own computer at a planned time**. For example I want every morming at 8:00 the program open a particular mp3 file. But suposse, by mistake, that I on my computer and 9:00, then I want that the program rememberme what I planned to open at 8:00.
- **Show me the program as an active windows on my desktop.** The windows of the program opened is what the user is seeing (Is at the first place in the desktop)  and the rest of the  program windows are below.
- **Close programs or files in my own computer at a planned time**. For example I want that the program mp3 file that was opened at 8:00 was closed at 10:00 if at that time still be opened.
- **Detection of events**. For instance If I open particular videogame program. then a mp3 file (with a recording message arguing why I shouldn´t continue playing that videogame at work time) is opened.
- **Possibility of combine the features mentioned before each other.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find that Macro Express (http://www.macroexpress.com/)does what you want. It includes a powerful scripting ability. I have used it in the past to do similar things to what you describe.

Comment: Is there a free version?

Comment: I think you will have to pay, but last I knew its not very expensive. For a single user, US$40 is nix.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in **Task Scheduler** of Windows can do most of that, assisted by command line utilities that [allow you to activate windows and close them](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). For the detection of events, you could replace the shortcut by a batch file that first displays a warning with OK / Cancel and starts when you click Cancel.

<sub>(I misinterpreted your question as usage tracking earlier, for which I've suggested [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/))</sub>